# 18.04.1: 5.0.0-37 kernel takes 56.393s; how to speed it up?

Tags: boot, kernel, performance

By system boot time is

systemd-analyze

Startup finished in 30.255s (firmware) + 13.235s (loader) + 56.393s (kernel) + 31.582s (userspace) = 2min 11.467s

uname -a

Linux AI 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[my disk partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr1x3.png)
[Is something wrong here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YACU.jpg)

systemd-analyze blame

```
     49.528s fstrim.service
     21.427s lvm2-monitor.service
      6.367s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.755s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      1.423s dev-sda3.device
      1.316s snapd.service
      1.231s systemd-journal-flush.service
       818ms fwupd.service
       652ms mysql.service
       452ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-123.mount
       447ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-81.mount
       420ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-98.mount
       414ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
       396ms upower.service
       357ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-90.mount
       355ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount
       317ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-544.mount
       298ms systemd-logind.service
       288ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
       277ms systemd-udevd.service
       248ms snap-core-8268.mount
       237ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
       233ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-375.mount
       232ms snap-core18-1650.mount
       231ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
       223ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-110.mount
       177ms tlp.service
       169ms dev-loop1.device
       159ms libvirtd.service
       157ms udisks2.service
       156ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       148ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
       147ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1440.mount
       145ms ModemManager.service
       143ms keyboard-setup.service
       139ms accounts-daemon.service
       116ms snap-core-4917.mount
```

journalctl -u fstrim

Jan 20 00:00:30 AI systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr1x3.png): Starting Discard unused blocks...

Jan 20 00:01:20 AI fstrim[4611]: /home: 314.8 GiB (338017718272 bytes) trimmed

Jan 20 00:01:20 AI fstrim[4611]: /boot/efi: 562.5 MiB (589815808 bytes) trimmed

Jan 20 00:01:20 AI fstrim[4611]: /: 101.6 GiB (109082742784 bytes) trimmed

Jan 20 00:01:20 AI systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr1x3.png): Started Discard unused blocks.

-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-01-13 00:00:36 IST, end at Mon 2020-01-20 03:17:01 IST. --

Jan 20 00:00:30 AI systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr1x3.png): Starting Discard unused blocks...

Jan 20 00:01:20 AI fstrim[4611]: /home: 314.8 GiB (338017718272 bytes) trimmed

Jan 20 00:01:20 AI fstrim[4611]: /boot/efi: 562.5 MiB (589815808 bytes) trimmed

Jan 20 00:01:20 AI fstrim[4611]: /: 101.6 GiB (109082742784 bytes) trimmed

Jan 20 00:01:20 AI systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr1x3.png): Started Discard unused blocks.

Comment: Please post the results of `systemd-analyze blame`; add to your question (text, not picture).

Comment: Done I added that

Comment: The **fstrim** service should only run once a week, so I wouldn't worry about that yet, although it shouldn't be taking that long. Unless you're using LVM, you can disable **lvm2-monitor** service. Can you post the results of `journalctl -u fstrim`?

Comment: Done I added that

Comment: I tried after disable fstrim and still the time is 56sec

Comment: Hmmm...you might want to install the smart monitor and check your drive; also rerun `systemd-analyze blame` after you disabled **fstrim**.